# Why is not possible to have a queue implemented as a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, queue, implementation

What are the drawbacks of using a std::vector for simulating a queue? I am naively thinking that push_back is used for push and for pop one just stores the position of the first element and increments it. Why does not std::queue allow a std::vector implementation like this in principle (I know the reason is it has no push_front method, but maybe there is something deeper that makes it slow this way)? Thank you for helping.

Comment: A vector only have push and pop operations for the *back* of the vector, while a queue requires push at one end and pop from the other. It's possible to create a queue using other functions (like `insert` and `erase`) but `std::queue` uses push and pop operations on the underlying container.

Comment: *"I am naively thinking that [...]"* -- you might want to continue thinking down these lines, only give the job of storing the position of the first element to the underlying container. If you work out some technicalities, you might find your "enhanced vector" resembles a [`deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque). *So, good thinking.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does not std::queue allow a std::vector implementation like this

`std::queue` is a simple container adapter. It works by delegating `pop` function to the `pop_front` function of the underlying container. Vector has no pop front operation, so `std::queue` cannot adapt it.

> but maybe there is something deeper that makes it slow this way

Pushing and popping from the front of the vector is slow because it has to shift all elements which has linear cost. This is why vector doesn't provide `pop_front`.

> stores the position of the first element and increments it.

It's possible to implement a container that does store the position of first element within a buffer, but vector is not an implementation of such container. Storing that position has an overhead that vector doesn't need to pay, and so it doesn't.